# Applying a method to members of a class

Tags: c#

Say I have a C# class:

```
public class Node
{
    public double A { get; set; }
    public double B { get; set; }
}
```

...and another class that includes a list of objects of that type:

```
public Buffer
{
    private List<Node> _nodes;
    ...
}
```

Now, say I need to calculate the sum of the values of A for the Node objects in the _nodes list. Then (separately) calculate the sum of B. Is there a way to do this using a 'generic' Sum() method, without having to duplicate code?

For example, one approach could be:

```
public class Buffer
{
    ...

    private double SumA()
    {
        double sum;

        foreach (Node node in _nodes)
        {
            sum += node.A;
        }

        return sum;
    }

    private double SumB()
    {
        double sum;

        foreach (Node node in _nodes)
        {
            sum += node.B;
        }

        return sum;
    }
}
```

The problem here is that the basic algorithm implemented by SumA() and SumB() is the same but in the case above is duplicated. This is compounded if Node has more properties, which needs summing, or if Sum() is a much more complicated process (both of which are true in the case I'm currently refactoring).

So to put the question another way, is there a way I can have a single Sum() method but have it operate on whichever member(s) of class Node within the list that I need to sum?

Comment: Look into passing a `Lambda Expression`.

Comment: Pass by reference into a generic `Sum` method.

Comment: @tnw: How does pass by reference help at all here?

Comment: @JonSkeet Ah, I misread the question. It doesn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a delegate to obtain the actual property to sum up.

```
private double Sum(Func<Node, double> selector)
{
    double sum = 0;

    foreach (Node node in _nodes)
    {
        sum += selector(node);
    }

    return sum;
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
var sumOfA = Sum(x => x.A);
var sumOfB = Sum(x => x.B);
```

This is a general purpose answer which will work for every algoritm.

But if you really just want to sum those values, you can use LINQ:

```
var sumOfA = _nodes.Sum(x => x.A);
var sumOfB = _nodes.Sum(x => x.B);
```

This would remove the need for your own `Sum` method.

Comment: @cadrell0: Please see update. My answer is meant as general purpose. However, I added a paragraph about LINQ.

Comment: Note that you need to set `sum` to 0 at the start for this to compile.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Fixed, thanks. I just copied that part from the question.

Comment: Many thanks for your help Daniel - I've now successfully implemented your suggestion in my code.

Answer (score 8):

You should look to LINQ for inspiration, and also for implementation, using a delegate to represent the projection of a `Node` to a `double`. For example, you could write:

```
private double SumB(Func<Node, double> selector)
{
    return _nodes.Sum(selector);
}
```

Then use it as:

```
double sumA = Sum(node => node.A);
```

Or if you're only using it internally (your method is currently private), don't bother with the method at all:

```
double sumA = _nodes.Sum(node => node.A);
```

If you need callers outside the class to be able to do this, you could either make your `Sum` public, or if you're already exposing `_nodes` somehow (e.g. as an `IEnumerable<Node>`) then external code could use:

```
double sumA = buffer.Nodes.Sum(node => node.A);
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help Jon - extremely helpful and I've now successfully implemented your / Daniels suggestions. Now checking out LINQ!

Answer (score 1):

Using LINQ you can simplify the sum to a point where the duplication is really minor:

```
double sumA = _nodes.Sum(node => node.A);
double sumB = _nodes.Sum(node => node.B);
```

If you want to hide _nodes but expose a sum-method you can do it like this:

```
private double Sum(Func<Node, double> selector)
{
    return _nodes.Sum(selector);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**PropertyInfo** is like a reference to the member (a property in this case):

```
PropertyInfo info = typeof(Node).GetProperty("A");
double sum = 0;
foreach (Node node in _nodes) sum += (double)info.GetValue(node, null);
```

And add:

```
using System.Reflection;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably also create an extension method for any List type

```
public class Buffer
{
    private List<Node> _nodes;
    private List<double> numsA;

    void MyMethod()
    {
        List<double> numsA = new List<double>();
        List<double> numsB = new List<double>();

        foreach (Node node in _nodes)
        {
            numsA.Add(node.A);
            numsB.Add(node.B);
        }
        double sumA = numsA.Sum();
        double sumB = numsB.Sum();
    }
}

public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static double Sum(this List<double> nodes)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        foreach (double node in nodes)
        {
            sum += node;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: No need for that. LINQ already has this and it even more generic as it works for every `IEnumerable<T>` and not just for `List<double>`.